# ELF: How to make IDA show me the correct PLT (Procedure Linkage Table) content?

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython, elf, plt

I would like to make IDA disassemble the `.plt` section of ELF files correctly, e.g. as objdump does:

```
objdump -D -M intel asdf | grep "Disassembly of section .plt" -A80
```

[image: objdump disassembly]

I don't know why but IDA gives me this (Note the `dw ?` and `dq ?`):
[image: IDA disassembly]

Even the IDA hexeditor does not show me the correct values at the corresponding addresses, but gives me `??`s.

I tried selecting and deselecting the settings described in the [IDA Online help](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1375.shtml) (search for "PLT") but this didn't help...

> 0: Replace PIC form of 'Procedure Linkage Table' to non PIC form
>
> 1: Direct jumping from PLT (without GOT) regardless of its form
>
> 2: Convert PIC form of loading `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_[]` of address
>
> 3: Obliterate auxiliary bytes in PLT & GOT for 'final autoanalysis'
>
> 4: Natural form of PIC GOT address loading in relocatable file
>
> 5: Unpatched form of PIC GOT references in relocatable file

How can I configure IDA so that I can access the instructions in the `.plt` section of an ELF file with IDAPython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 32bit (but *not* 64bit) x86 ELF binary, selecting the following options works:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

There is a bug in IDA 6.8 (and probably earlier versions): For 64bit x86 ELF binaries, I get the desired disassembly result only when additionally deselecting "Replace PIC form of ...".

This was the reason for my confusion and made me post my question.

Hex-rays sent me a patch which fixed it (and which will probably be part of future versions... )

Comment: hello, how do you reach the settings "ELF patching (for PIC) and viewing mode" ? I can not find it

Comment: @user3097712 : In the "Load a new file" window, select "Loading options". See the checkmark in the left-hand screen shot. After that, the window you are asking for should appear automatically after hitting ok in the "Load a new file" window. Please tell me if it works.

Comment: @user3097712 : if this works for you, you can of course upvote my answer :- )